# Why Does sRGB Have Superfluous Colors?

Tags: colors, rgb

- The Visible Spectrum is roughly 3 times the size of the sRGB Gamut.
- The sRGB Gamut can display over 16 million colors (256 x 256 x 256).
- Most humans can only see roughly 10 million colors.
- Regarding the distance between colors in the sRGB Gamut, if the same was used on the entire Visible Spectrum, then that'd result in about 50 million colors.

If we can't even see 16 million colors in the entire Visible Spectrum, then why was the sRGB Gamut coded with so many colors? It seems as if around 3 million would've sufficed. Isn't it also wasteful to provide so much more?

Answer (score 2):

Because it's not about the number of colours that can be seen, it is about the accuracy of them.

The human eye can distinguish certain colours better than others and one of the problems of having a colour space that is too small or is too close to the size of the visual colour space you see is that there are going to be times when a shade of pinky-green is going to get adjusted to fit the colour space and end up a shade of greeny-pink.

Having a larger colour space means that colours will always end up closer to their real value.

The human eye also works on differences in contrast and brightness and, despite having limited colour perception, can actually differentiate between similar-yet-different colours.

With a larger colour space you can also have more gentle gradients between colours. You might not be able to see the individual colours, but you can perceive that the colour gradient is more natural and consistent rather than it being quantised across a smaller range.

Comment: I understand the risk of cutting it close to the precise quantity that the average human could see in sRGB. Still, even if 3 million is riskily low, couldn't perhaps 8 million suffice (more than double the amount that the average human could actually detect)? I wondered if part of the issue was wanting a number that's a quadric of 2 for each primary color.